# Using apache poi ant in eclipse

Tags: excel, ant, import, apache-poi, export-to-excel

I have installed "EE developers" software and also "XML editors and tools" on my eclipse and I want to use apache poi to read some data from excel files but when eclipse compiles my code, it gives me an error.

In fact it cannot support the following imports. why do I get this problem?

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
```

Cheers

Comment: Think your missing the poi.jar from your build's classpath. http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22org.apache.poi%22%20AND%20a%3A%22poi%22

Comment: I have added poi.jar to my buildpath as well, but it is still not working. can you think of any other issues?

Comment: Which buildpath? ANT and Eclipse use different mechanism's for managing classpath's. ANT has a "path" task, Eclipse uses a separate ".classpath" file.

Comment: oh, I didn't know that. I just right click on my project and go on the properties -> java build path -> libraries -> add jars 
and then I add poi. jar 
but I suppose this is the wrong method. 
can you please tell me how I should add it to the ant classpath?

Answer (score 0):

The [ANT tutorial](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html#ext-libs) explains how external libraries are managed by ANT.

```
<project name="HelloWorld" basedir="." default="main">
    ...
    <property name="lib.dir"     value="lib"/>

    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </path>

    ...

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath"/>
    </target>

    ...

</project>
```